# How do you convert a five year treasury future to an readable price?

Tags: futures

I closed out on a five year treasury note (FVH22) at a price of 119'14.7 (trade station brokerage).  Does that convert to 119+14.7/32?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tick size in ZF, aka FV, is 128ths, i.e. 1/4 of 1/32nd. Most likely "119'14.7" means 119+14.75/32. See https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/interest-rates/us-treasury/5-year-us-treasury-note.contractSpecs.html.

I'm not familiar with TradeStation's quotation conventions so you should verify this with them directly.

Comment: The way I think of it: The digit to the right of decimal point (in this case 7) can only be 0,2,5,7. If it is 2 or 7 then there is a 'hidden' 5 digit to the right of it. I.e. 0.7 stands for 0.75, though they don't show you the 5 to save space. Some web sites (for ex. Cmegroup.Com) leave the decimal point out: 119'147 to save even more space